# java file within Maven project no longer has "run as java application" option

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a java file within a Maven project that I used to get the "run as java application" option on.  I re-imported the code from SVN as it seemed something might have been corrupted.  I can compile and create a .war file, but I can't seem to get the "run as java application" option back.  I tried going into run configurations, but when I put my Maven project name into the project it says i'm trying to reference a non-existing project.  In my Maven project, it says the type is a project, so I'm wondering why it's not showing up in the project list.

And how do I get the "run as java application" option back?  I haven't changed the .java file at all since the last time it worked.  It has the necessary public static void main, so i'm not sure what else to try.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Run --> Run Configurations ---> Java Application --> Add your Jre, etc.

Comment: Thanks!  That helped somewhat I think.  I still wasn't able to run as it says i'm still referencing a non-existing project.  However, I now have the "run on server" option.  Need the "run as java app" option though.

Comment: FYI the change i made was to set my execution environment to JavaSE-1.6(jdk1.6.0_45).

Comment: Make a new Java Application Run Platform, in the same option. If you directly imported the project, I recommend you making a thing: Instead importing, try a NEW Java Project and tell Eclipse the directory of your srcs.

Comment: Are you in a java perspective (package, etc.)?

Comment: I was told that a direct import was the best way, but until that person gets back to me, i'm going to try this way again since I had it working before.  I can get it to run my file now.  I see some odd things, but I think it's due to how I set up the project.  So that's a different issue.  Thanks for the prompt help!

Comment: Yes, I'm in java perspective.